# JSF setting dropdown list

Tags: jsf

I'm trying to create a dropdown box in JSF. It needs to be filled with numbers within a given valid range. So example if the given range is between **5 and 20** than the dropdown values should be;

```
  "5, 10 15, 20"
```

I have some problems, In my controller I create something like this and set values with a for loop;

```
List<Integer> validAmounts  OR
List<String>  validAmounts
```

Then

```
  <myapp:selectRowElem id="autoreloadamount"
            type="dropdown" selectItems="#{settingsController.validAmounts}"/>
```

I get error saying something like

```
itemValue="#{i.value}": String does not have a property 'value'
```

Any Ideas?

Also is there a better **"JSF" way** of setting the valid amounts but not creating a for loop in my controller to set the validAmounts list ?

"**myapp:selectRowElem**" is long but it has this for dropdown;

```
 <h:selectOneMenu id="input" value="#{cc.attrs.item}" validatorMessage="#{msg[validatorMsgKey]}">
                            <f:validateRequired disabled="#{cc.attrs.forceRequired ne 'true'}"/>
                            <f:selectItems value="#{cc.attrs.selectItems}" var="i" itemValue="#{i.value}" itemLabel="#{i.label}" />
                        </h:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: The problem is in code behind `<portal:selectRowElem>` which isn't recognizable as part of standard JSF API and thus likely homegrown or 3rd party. As long as you tell nothing about that part, it's unlikely that anyone could give you an answer. If I may do a wild guess, it's actually expecting a `List<SelectItem>`.

Comment: @BalusC I coudl make it work using h:selectOneMenu instead of selectRowElem but then all styling is gone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This,

```
<f:selectItems value="#{cc.attrs.selectItems}" var="i" itemValue="#{i.value}" itemLabel="#{i.label}" />
```

expects a `List<SomeObject>` as `#{cc.attrs.selectItems}` wherein each `SomeObject` item is been assigned as loop variable `#{i}` which in turn is expected to have `getValue()` and `getLabel()` methods returning the item value and label respectively.

Neither `Integer` nor `String` have those getter methods. This is also exactly what the exception is trying to tell you in case of a `String`. It couldn't find the `getValue()` method on it.

It appears that the `#{cc.attrs.selectItems}` is expecting a `List<SelectItem>` wherein the `SelectItem` is the standard JSF `javax.faces.model.SelectItem` object [which **does** have those getters](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/model/SelectItem.html).

So you should be declaring and creating the list as follows:

```
List<SelectItem> validAmounts; 

// ...

validAmounts = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
validAmounts.add(new SelectItem(5));
validAmounts.add(new SelectItem(10));
validAmounts.add(new SelectItem(15));
validAmounts.add(new SelectItem(20));
```

A technically valid alternative is to create a custom class like `SomeObject` with those getter methods returning the desired values. But this reinvention of the wheel is after all functionally plain clumsy and therefore not recommended.

---

This all by the way indicates at least 2 problems in the `<portal:selectRowElem>` composite component which is apparently developed by someone else:

1. The `<cc:attribute name="selectItems">` is missing the `shortDescription` attribute which should clearly explain the enduser (you) what value exactly it expects. It should tell that it's expecting a `List<SelectItem>`. This way you should immediately have noticed it during code autocomplete or by just glancing the tag documentation.
2. All those `var`, `itemLabel` and `itemValue` attributes are completely superfluous. They are all the defaults already when a `List<SelectItem>` is been supplied. This also indicates that the original composite component developer had no idea what he was doing.

Comment: Thanks! is there  way to set the width of the dropdown without modifying the composite component?

Comment: You're welcome. For new questions, just press `Ask Question` button on right top.

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19182887/jsf-how-to-set-dropdown-width